# Entity Framework Core can not add migration

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-migrations

Executing `dotnet ef add migration InitialMigration` command giving this error `A suitable constructor for type 'Vega.Repository.VegaContext' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.`

My `ConfigureServices` method on Startup class is following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{            
   services.AddMvc();       
   services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
   var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("VegaConnection");
   services.AddDbContext<VegaContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
}
```

`VegaContext` class is:

```
public class VegaContext : DbContext
{
    VegaContext(DbContextOptions<VegaContext> options):base(options)
    {}
    public DbSet<Make> Makes { get; set; }
}
```

Part of `csproj` file is:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.2" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Try to add parameter-less constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is exactly what you´ve posted, the solution is pretty simple. Just make your DbContext-constructor public and everything should be fine:

```
public class VegaContext : DbContext
{
    public VegaContext(DbContextOptions<VegaContext> options):base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Make> Makes { get; set; }
}
```